# how to add a safe area constraint to the bottom of an inputAccessoryView swift4/ios11/xcode9

Tags: ios11, xcode9, swift4, inputaccessoryview, safearealayoutguide

I have an inputAccessoryView which I am using for text input in a chat app.

Selecting the iPhone X, the bottom of the inputAccessoryView is infringing on the safe area and partially obscured.

Is there a way to add a safe area constraint to the inputAccessoryView?  Rather than having to manually adjust inputAccessoryView frame height specifically for the iPhone X when keyboard is hidden?

Comment: I am researching on the same. Try this: https://bobbyprabowo.com/post/inputaccessoryview-on-ios-11/

Answer (score 1):

Using this code to set your bottom anchor should keep your view within the safe area

```
inputAccessoryView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Please change height to desire. It's bug of interface builder, probably.